# Previous and older set of posts links

Tags: links, previous

I can't seem to display previous and older set of posts links. [This](http://akselgumus.com/wordpress1/show06/) is the page I am working on. I need a link to older and newer posts at the bottom of page.

The template code is like this:

```
<?php /*
Template Name: artikkelit
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<div class="postPic"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>

</main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Any suggestions on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

The other question is completely wrong and should not be used

- [`previous_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post) and [`next_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post) is both depreciated functions and should not be used anymore
- Never replace `WP_Query` with `query_posts` to solve a problem. This actually creates more. Also, `query_posts` should **never** be used
- `showposts` is also depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`

To make pagination work, you will need to do the following instead

- Set the `paged` parameter in your query arguments (`paged=$paged`)

  ```
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  ```
- Use [`previous_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link) and [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) to paginate your posts
- Set the `$max_num_pages` parameter for `next_posts_link()` as to correctly calculate the amount of pages when using a custom query

Your query should look something like this. (*Taken from the codex*)

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```